# Javascript DOM issue. (getElementsByClassName)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have 3 divs , the first one is with id , the second two with same class. I've written an EventListeners with javascript for these 3 divs. The eventlistener for my first div , which is related with an ID works , but the second function which is related to getElementsByClassName() doesn't work. Here's my code

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var firstElement = document.getElementById('firstOne');
  firstOne.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    this.style.border = '5px outset #00FF1E';
  });

  var secondElements = document.getElementsByClassName('secondOne');
  secondElements.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < secondElements.length; i++) {
      secondElements[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#firstOne {
  height: 240px;
  width: 240px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
}
.secondOne {
  height: 240px;
  width: 240px;
  border: 5px solid green;
  background-color: skyblue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="firstOne"></div>
<div class="secondOne"></div>
<div class="secondOne"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`. Since you are doing `secondElements.addEventListener`, it will throw an error 
because you cannot attach events to a `NodeList`. You always attach events to a `Node`.

To fix this, loop over the elements of the `NodeList` using a for-loop (or a `.apply-forEach` combo if you are comfortable with that), and attach event listener individually.

`document.getElementById` always returns a `Node` (since there can only be one element with a particular `id` in the DOM) and so `firstOne.addEventListener` works.

**Code sample:**

```
var secondElements = document.getElementsByClassName('secondOne');

for(var i = 0, len = secondElements.length, elm; i < len; i++){
    elm = secondElements[i];

    elm.addEventListener('click', your_handler_function_here);
}
```

Comment: Okay , I understand.So there's no way to apply a style to multiple elements with getElementsByClassName()? So what about querySelector() method ?? If I do a variable with value = document.querySelector('.secondOne').addEventListener('click',function(){..}); will it work?

Comment: `document.querySelector` only returns a `Node`, so it would work. But remember that it would grab only the first appearance of the matched element. And the other matching nodes will be missed by that method. As I said, if you want to use `getElementsByClassName`, you can loop over the individual elements of the Nodelist returned by it and then manually attach listener to each of them.

Comment: which means if I have 2 divs with same class , and use querySelector , will catch only the first div ? And another question is , if i use querySelector() method, can I write the function inside like querySelector('items').addEventListener('click',function(){..}) or , I have to define the function outside this one and use it only by name , like querySelector('items').addEventListener('click',changeColor);

Comment: @Nasco.Chachev Yes. I will give you a code example. Wait.

Comment: @Nasco.Chachev See updated answer

Comment: BRo , i have an issue , i've tried to do it with querySelector , but maybe again returns NodeList... var secondElements = document.querySelector('div.secondOne');
 secondElements.addEventListener('click',function(){
  for(var i = 0;i<secondElements.length;i++){
   secondElements[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
 });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97847/discussion-between-gaurang-tandon-and-nasco-chachev).

Answer (score 2):

**getElementsByClassName()**  return an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

use `for()` to loop it, and add `click` event;

```
    var secondElements = document.getElementsByClassName('secondOne');

    for (var i=0;i<secondElements.length; i++) {
       secondElements[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
           for(var i = 0; i < secondElements.length ; i++){
              secondElements[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            }
        });
     }
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/yqec6aqs/